# check data with multiple 'in' result

Tags: oracle

It seems a stupid question, but how to get multiple 'in' result ?

I have 2 tables(tab1,tab2) with the the same 2 columns : table_name and column_name.

I want to check the data in table_name and column_name in tab1 that doest not exists in tab2

this query is wrong but similar to what I want:

```
  select distinct s.table_name , s.column_name from tab1 s   where
 (S.table_name ,s.column_name) not in ((select table_name from tab2 ,
 (select column_name from tab2))
```

Comment: You mean that you want to select row where table_name and column_name are in tab1, but there isn't matching row in tab2?

Comment: I can do this query for one column : select table name from tab1 where table_name not in ( select table_name from tab2)... how to do it for 2 column ? table_name and column_name @rzysia

Comment: what about `select table_name from tab1 where table_name not in (select table_name from tab2) and column_name not in (select column_name from tab2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to eliminate rows where pairs (tname, tcolumn) are present in second table then:

```
select distinct s.table_name, s.column_name 
  from tab1 s
  where (s.table_name, s.column_name) 
    not in (select table_name, column_name from tab2)
```

... and if you want to eliminate everything, if tname or tcolumn exists in table2:

```
select distinct s.table_name, s.column_name 
  from tab1 s
  where s.table_name not in (select table_name from tab2)
    and s.column_name not in (select column_name from tab2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  s.table_name , s.column_name 
from tab1 s
MINUS
select  t.table_name , t.column_name 
from tab2 t;
```

This should give the data that is only in tab1

Answer (score 1):

There is always the option of using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.table_name, s.column_name
  FROM tab1 s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tab1 t
                     WHERE t.table_name = s.table_name
                       AND t.column_name = s.column_name );
```